# Initializing boost::asio socket after constructor failed

Tags: c++, sockets, boost, boost-asio, shared-ptr

I create a class to broadcast UDP messages as follows:

```
#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS
#include <ctime>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <queue>
#include <boost/array.hpp>
#include <boost/bind.hpp>
#include <boost/shared_ptr.hpp>
#include <boost/asio.hpp>
#include <boost/lexical_cast.hpp>
#include <boost/thread.hpp>
#include <boost/thread/thread.hpp> 
#include <boost/chrono.hpp>
#include <boost/date_time/posix_time/posix_time.hpp>

using boost::asio::ip::udp;
using std::cout;
using std::cin;
using std::endl;
using std::string;
using namespace std;

template<typename T>
std::string toString(const T& value);
std::string IntToString(const int& i);

class UdpCore
{
private:
    boost::asio::ip::udp::endpoint endpoint;
    boost::asio::ip::udp::socket socket;

    string multicast_address;
    unsigned short multicast_port;
    boost::thread_group threads;    // thread group
    boost::thread* thread_main;     // main thread
    boost::thread* thread_listen;   // listen thread
    boost::thread* thread_getsend;  // get/send thread
    boost::mutex stopMutex;
    bool initialize = false;
    bool stop, showBroadcast;
    int i_getsend, i_listen, i_main, i_message, interval;
    string message;
public:
    // constructor
    UdpCore(boost::asio::io_service& io_service, std::string multicast_address, unsigned short multicast_port, int interval, bool show = false)
        : endpoint(boost::asio::ip::address::from_string(multicast_address), multicast_port),
        socket(io_service, endpoint.protocol()),
        multicast_address(multicast_address),
        multicast_port(multicast_port),
        interval(interval),
        showBroadcast(show)
    {
        Initialize(io_service, show);
    }

    ~UdpCore()
    {
        // show exit message
        cout << "Exiting UDP Core." << endl;
    }

    // initialize
    void Initialize(boost::asio::io_service& io_service, bool show = false)
    {
        if (initialize == false)
        {
            GetInfo();
        }

        boost::asio::ip::udp::endpoint endpoint(boost::asio::ip::make_address(multicast_address), multicast_port);
        boost::asio::ip::udp::socket socket(io_service, endpoint.protocol());
        socket.set_option(boost::asio::ip::udp::socket::reuse_address(true));   // no need

        thread_main = new boost::thread(boost::ref(*this));
        thread_getsend = new boost::thread(&UdpCore::Callable_GetSend, this, interval, boost::ref(i_listen), boost::ref(message));
        threads.add_thread(thread_getsend); // get/send thread
        stop = false;
        showBroadcast = show;
        i_getsend = 0;
        i_listen = 0;
        i_main = 0;
        i_message = 0;
        message.clear();

        initialize = true;
    }

    void GetInfo()
    {
        multicast_address = "192.168.0.255";
        multicast_port = 13000;
        interval = 500;
    }

    // start the threads
    void Start()
    {
        // Wait till they are finished
        threads.join_all();
    }

    // stop the threads
    void Stop()
    {
        // warning message
        cout << "Stopping all threads." << endl;

        // signal the threads to stop (thread-safe)
        stopMutex.lock();
        stop = true;
        stopMutex.unlock();

        // wait for the threads to finish
        thread_main->interrupt();   // in case not interrupted by operator()
        threads.interrupt_all();
        threads.join_all();

        // close socket after everything closes
        socket.close();
    }

    void Callable_Listen(int interval, int& count)
    {
        while (!stop)
        {
            if (message != "")
                socket.async_send_to(boost::asio::buffer(message), endpoint, [this](boost::system::error_code ec, std::size_t /*length*/)
            {
                stopMutex.lock();
                if (showBroadcast)
                {
                    cout << i_message << " - " << message << endl;  // show  count
                }
                message.clear();    //clear after sending
                stopMutex.unlock();
            });
            ++i_message;

            // wait routine
            boost::this_thread::sleep(boost::posix_time::millisec(interval));
            boost::this_thread::interruption_point();
            ++i_listen;
        }
    }

    void Callable_GetSend(int interval, int& count, string& userInput)
    {
        while (!stop)
        {
            stopMutex.lock();
            cout << "Callable_GetSend [" << count++ << "]. Enter message: ";
            getline(cin, userInput);
            if (message != "")
                socket.async_send_to(boost::asio::buffer(message), endpoint, [this](boost::system::error_code ec, std::size_t /*length*/)
            {
                if (showBroadcast)
                {
                    cout << i_message << " - " << message << endl;  // show  count
                }
                message.clear();    //clear after sending
            });
            stopMutex.unlock();

            // wait routine
            boost::this_thread::sleep(boost::posix_time::millisec(interval));
            boost::this_thread::interruption_point();
            ++i_getsend;
            ++i_message;
        }
    }

    // Thread function
    void operator () ()
    {
        while (!stop)
        {
            if (message == "STOP")
            {
                try
                {
                    this->Stop();
                }
                catch (exception e)
                {
                    cout << e.what() << endl;
                }
            }

            boost::this_thread::sleep(boost::posix_time::millisec(interval));
            boost::this_thread::interruption_point();
        }
    }

    std::string make_daytime_string()
    {
        using namespace std; // For time_t, time and ctime;
        time_t now = time(0);
        std::string result = ctime(&now);
        return result.erase(result.length() - 1, 1);
    }

    std::string some_string()
    {
        std::string result;
        result = make_daytime_string();
        return result;
    }
};

int main()
{
    try
    {
        boost::asio::io_service io_service;
        UdpCore mt(io_service, "192.168.0.255", 13000, 5000, false);
        mt.Start(); 
    }
    catch (std::exception& e)
    {
        std::cerr << "Exception: " << e.what() << "\n";
    }
}
```

It works fine.  However, I wish to initialize the socket after the class constructor is initialized (to allow user input).  Thus, I change from using socket to a socket pointer, as suggested by this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31371214/initializing-boostasio-sockets-after-constructor)
.  The modified code is as follows:

```
#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS
#include <ctime>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <queue>
#include <boost/array.hpp>
#include <boost/bind.hpp>
#include <boost/shared_ptr.hpp>
#include <boost/asio.hpp>
#include <boost/lexical_cast.hpp>
#include <boost/thread.hpp>
#include <boost/thread/thread.hpp> 
#include <boost/chrono.hpp>
#include <boost/date_time/posix_time/posix_time.hpp>

using boost::asio::ip::udp;
using std::cout;
using std::cin;
using std::endl;
using std::string;
using namespace std;

template<typename T>
std::string toString(const T& value);
std::string IntToString(const int& i);

class UdpCore
{
private:
    boost::asio::ip::udp::endpoint endpoint;
    boost::shared_ptr<udp::socket> socketPtr;

    string multicast_address;
    unsigned short multicast_port;
    boost::thread_group threads;    // thread group
    boost::thread* thread_main;     // main thread
    boost::thread* thread_listen;   // listen thread
    boost::thread* thread_getsend;  // get/send thread
    boost::mutex stopMutex;
    bool initialize = false;
    bool stop, showBroadcast;
    int i_getsend, i_listen, i_main, i_message, interval;
    string message;
public:
    // constructor
    UdpCore(boost::asio::io_service& io_service, std::string multicast_address, unsigned short multicast_port, int interval, bool show = false)
        : multicast_address(multicast_address),
        multicast_port(multicast_port),
        interval(interval),
        showBroadcast(show)
    {
        UdpCore(io_service, show);
    }

    UdpCore(boost::asio::io_service& io_service, bool show = false)
        : showBroadcast(show)
    {
        Initialize(io_service, show);
    }

    // destructor
    ~UdpCore()
    {
        // show exit message
        cout << "Exiting UDP Core." << endl;
    }

    // initialize
    void Initialize(boost::asio::io_service& io_service, bool show = false)
    {
        if (initialize == false)
        {
            GetInfo();
        }

        boost::asio::ip::udp::endpoint endpoint(boost::asio::ip::address::from_string(multicast_address), multicast_port);
        socketPtr = boost::make_shared<udp::socket>(boost::ref(io_service), endpoint.protocol());
        socketPtr->set_option(boost::asio::ip::udp::socket::reuse_address(true));   // no need

        thread_main = new boost::thread(boost::ref(*this));
        thread_getsend = new boost::thread(&UdpCore::Callable_GetSend, this, interval, boost::ref(i_listen), boost::ref(message));
        threads.add_thread(thread_getsend); // get/send thread
        stop = false;
        showBroadcast = show;
        i_getsend = 0;
        i_listen = 0;
        i_main = 0;
        i_message = 0;
        message.clear();

        initialize = true;
    }

    void GetInfo()
    {
        multicast_address = "192.168.0.255";
        multicast_port = 13000;
        interval = 500;
    }

    // start the threads
    void Start()
    {
        // Wait till they are finished
        threads.join_all();
    }

    // stop the threads
    void Stop()
    {
        // warning message
        cout << "Stopping all threads." << endl;

        // signal the threads to stop (thread-safe)
        stopMutex.lock();
        stop = true;
        stopMutex.unlock();

        // wait for the threads to finish
        thread_main->interrupt();   // in case not interrupted by operator()
        threads.interrupt_all();
        threads.join_all();

        // close socket after everything closes
        socketPtr->close();
    }

    void Callable_Listen(int interval, int& count)
    {
        while (!stop)
        {
            if (message != "")
                socketPtr->async_send_to(boost::asio::buffer(message), endpoint, [this](boost::system::error_code ec, std::size_t /*length*/)
            {
                stopMutex.lock();
                if (showBroadcast)
                {
                    cout << i_message << " - " << message << endl;  // show  count
                }
                message.clear();    //clear after sending
                stopMutex.unlock();
            });
            ++i_message;

            // wait routine
            boost::this_thread::sleep(boost::posix_time::millisec(interval));
            boost::this_thread::interruption_point();
            ++i_listen;
        }
    }

    void Callable_GetSend(int interval, int& count, string& userInput)
    {
        while (!stop)
        {
            stopMutex.lock();
            cout << "Callable_GetSend [" << count++ << "]. Enter message: ";
            getline(cin, userInput);
            if (message != "")
                socketPtr->async_send_to(boost::asio::buffer(message), endpoint, [this](boost::system::error_code ec, std::size_t /*length*/)
            {
                if (showBroadcast)
                {
                    cout << i_message << " - " << message << endl;  // show  count
                }
                message.clear();    //clear after sending
            });
            stopMutex.unlock();

            // wait routine
            boost::this_thread::sleep(boost::posix_time::millisec(interval));
            boost::this_thread::interruption_point();
            ++i_getsend;
            ++i_message;
        }
    }

    // Thread function
    void operator () ()
    {
        while (!stop)
        {
            if (message == "STOP")
            {
                try
                {
                    this->Stop();
                }
                catch (exception e)
                {
                    cout << e.what() << endl;
                }
            }

            boost::this_thread::sleep(boost::posix_time::millisec(interval));
            boost::this_thread::interruption_point();
        }
    }

    std::string make_daytime_string()
    {
        using namespace std; // For time_t, time and ctime;
        time_t now = time(0);
        std::string result = ctime(&now);
        return result.erase(result.length() - 1, 1);
    }

    std::string some_string()
    {
        std::string result;
        result = make_daytime_string();
        return result;
    }
};

int main()
{
    try
    {
        boost::asio::io_service io_service;
        UdpCore mt(io_service, false);
        mt.Start();
    }
    catch (std::exception& e)
    {
        std::cerr << "Exception: " << e.what() << "\n";
    }
}
```

where I have these replacements:

```
//boost::asio::ip::udp::socket socket;
boost::shared_ptr<udp::socket> socketPtr;

//boost::asio::ip::udp::socket socket(io_service, endpoint.protocol());
//socket.set_option(boost::asio::ip::udp::socket::reuse_address(true));
socketPtr = boost::make_shared<udp::socket>(boost::ref(io_service), endpoint.protocol());
socketPtr->set_option(boost::asio::ip::udp::socket::reuse_address(true));

//socket.async_send_to(boost::asio::buffer(message), endpoint, [this](boost::system::error_code ec, std::size_t /*length*/)
socketPtr->async_send_to(boost::asio::buffer(message), endpoint, [this](boost::system::error_code ec, std::size_t /*length*/)
```

Just one thing with the modification: it doesn't work.  I keep poring over the code, and could not find the reason why it shouldn't work.  Could someone please help?

Comment: Could you be more specific please? What do you mean by saying "it does not work"?

Comment: @IgorR., my receiver code fails to show anything.  WireShark shows not successful transmission, unlike before switching to socket pointer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the first sample, besides the member `endpoint` and `socket`, you create a local `endpoint` and `socket` in `Initialize()` function. The latter objects are just unused - however, the member `endpoint` is properly initialized.

On the other hand, in the second example you do not properly initialize the member `endpoint`. Instead, you create again a local one. But pay attention that the endpoint used throughout the code is the member one.

The bottom line: remove the local objects and add correct initialization for the members.

Comment: Can you tell me how it is not properly initialized?  How can I correct them?  I could see no error.  Thanks.

Comment: @CaTx Take a look at UdpCore constructor's initialization list. You do there `endpoint(boost::asio::ip::address::from_string(multicast_address), multicast_port)`.   This line is missing in the 2nd example.

Comment: this is what I intended.  I wanted to initialize it later after I have the user input.  This is the same goal of this guy, and it seems he succeeded.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31371214/initializing-boostasio-sockets-after-constructor

Comment: @CaTx Do you want to setup the endpoint outside the ctor init list? You can do this, see asio reference for details. But currently you never initialize it at all. Instead, you create another local endpoint object, which is not used later. (Since you comment my answer, additional tagging is unneeded, so SO deletes it.)

Comment: Yes, I wish to initialize it after the ctor init list.  I thought this line initalizes the endpoint: boost::asio::ip::udp::endpoint endpoint(boost::asio::ip::address::from_string(multicast_address), multicast_port);

Comment: @CaTx Oh, it looks like you will have to create it dynamically as well, like the socket ([endpoint interface](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_66_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/ip__basic_endpoint.html) does not allow configuring the endpoint after its creation). And no - that line defines *another* object.

Comment: can you give me the link to said ASIO reference?

Comment: So how exactly do I have it initialize?  Thanks for pointing out.  I was a bit weirded out by that syntax.

Comment: @CaTx I answered that [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49247428/c-boost-initializing-endpoint-after-contructor).